# Drupal 8 - JSON API get with parameters

Tags: json, api, drupal, parameters, get

I can get the list of records I have of a custom content by creating a new "view" and setting the response returned in a JSON format

Now I would like to send a get request, with 1 or more parameters, and only return a subset of records whose fields match with my parameters

ex : www.exmample.com/rest/view/customcontent?city=paris

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a filter (add filter criteria) in the view. Make it exposed and change the **Filter identifier** field according what you want to have in the URL.